# Remote directory empty except for .ftpquota?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

See attached - imported xml that the client sent over. Claims I'm successfully connected but then the directory is almost empty - no PublicHTML. Would this be on my end or would it have to do with how permissions for me are set in their CPanel? I imagine this means I was not given access to the root folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you were given access to a Public_ftp folder where you can upload files and either a person or a script will move the uploaded files to the final destination folder.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Had to make sure it wasn't a permissions issue.